# Lubuntu 15.04 graphical issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu, 15.04, intel-graphics

I am using lubuntu 15.04 on an old pc

Intel pentium 1.70 ghz

256+512 MB ram

32 bit processor (no support for 64bit)

I used forcepae flag for launching it

There are graphical issues like scratching on texts or scratches on wallpaper.
Last time I get issue I was using galaxy ace (s5830i) and I was on a early beta of cm7.. issues are similar.

Should I wait for intel graphics driver for 15.04 or this issue caused by forcepae flag?

Comment: You might find this helpful. The tool will install the latest intel driver stack, but I'm not sure if it's been updated for 15.04. I would recommend using an LTS release if possible as support is always superior. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-1-0-5

Comment: this is not for 15.04 I already know this. I am not looking for driver links here. Just for answers. Why is this issue happening?

Comment: See my answer....

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the technical details for your CPU, but some but not all of these CPUs have PAE capability, but show no PAE flag (this can hinder installation as the software checks for the flag). There are a number of alternative methods discussed to get around this [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu-fake-PAE) Be that as it may, I would simply boot from the [Lubuntu 12.04 32-bit live disk](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/precise/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso) which doesn't need these workarounds. If you have the same problem doing that, I would look long and hard at replacing the graphics card as we've then eliminated the forcepae flag from the equation entirely.

Comment: 12.04 don't have Intel microcodes. I like it.

Comment: If this resolves your issue, please upvote/accept the answer so that others with the same issue can recognize a functional answer

Comment: Any answer solved my issue but if anyone interested in older builds that don't need pae then your post is the answer also I can't upvote

Comment: You can however accept by clicking the check mark which would indicate this is a valid answer you could confirm this by removing the forcepae flag from the equation as outlined in my answer.